# How to replace anchor element with the innerHTML of itself

Tags: javascript, html

I try to write a script based on JavaScript for replacing the current selected anchor element with it's inner HTML.

You can also find a simple running example in ***[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tad6L/2/)***. To run the example, click on the first link, and the click the button.

So, for example, if I have the following HTML:

```
<p>
    Wawef awef <a href="http://www.somesite.com/"><em>replace</em> <strong>me</strong></a>
    falwkefi4hjtinyoh gf waf eerngl nregsl ngsekdng selrgnlrekg slekngs ekgnselrg nselrg 
    <a href="http://www.anothersite.com/>replace me</a> klserng sreig klrewr
</p>
```

and I like when I click on some of the two anchors to remove the anchor with it's inner HTML. This mean, that if I click on the first anchor element, and click the appropriate button to replace the anchor the result should be like that:

```
<p>
    Wawef awef <em>replace</em> <strong>me</strong> falwkefi4hjtinyoh gf waf eerngl 
    nregsl ngsekdng selrgnlrekg slekngs ekgnselrg nselrg <a href="http://www.anothersite.com/>replace me</a>
    klserng sreig klrewr
</p>
```

My JavaScript code for this functionality is the following:

```
// Start tracking the click event on the document
document.addEventListener(
    'click',
    function(event)
    {
        // If right click, return
        if(event.button == 2)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Get the current clicked document element
        var link    =   event.target;

        while(link && !(link instanceof HTMLAnchorElement))
        {
            link    =   link.parentNode;
        }

        // Get the element with ID wpf-remove-element-now
        var clickedLink =   document.getElementById("wpf-remove-element-now");

        // If the element exists
        if(clickedLink !== null)
        {
            // By executing this code, I am ensuring that I have only
            // one anchor element in my document with this ID

            // Remove the id attribute
            clickedLink.removeAttribute('id');
        }

        // If ther is no link element
        if(!link)
        {
            // Disable my "unlink" button
            editor.commands.customunlinkcmd.disable();
            // and return
            return;
        }

        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        // If the user has clickde on an anchor element then
        // enable my "unlink" button in order to allow him to
        // to replace the link if he like to.
        editor.commands.customunlinkcmd.enable();

        // Set the id attribute of the current selected anchor
        // element to wpf-remove-element-now
        link.setAttribute('id', 'wpf-remove-element-now');
    }
);

var $unlink_button = document.getElementById('unlink');

$unlink_button.addEventListener(
    'click',
    function(event)
    {
        // Get the element with ID wpf-remove-element-now
        var link    =   document.getElementById("wpf-remove-element-now");
        // Create a new text node that contains the link inner HTML
        var text    =   document.createTextNode(link.innerHTML);

        // Make the replacement
        link.parentNode.replaceChild(text, link);
    }
);
```

Everything until now is correct, appart of the replacement of the link. I have try the above code, but the result I get is like the following one:

```
Wawef awef <em>replace</em> <strong>me</strong> falwkefi4hjtinyoh gf waf eerngl 
nregsl ngsekdng selrgnlrekg slekngs ekgnselrg nselrg replace me klserng sreig klrewr
```

I mean the anchor is replaced with the text form of the inner HTML and not with the HTML form of the inner HTML.

So the question is, how can I do this kind of replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was much simpler that I thought. I placed the solution below for anybody that need an equivalent solution :) :

```
$unlink_button.addEventListener(
    'click',
    function(event)
    {
        // Get the element with ID wpf-remove-element-now
        var link          =    document.getElementById("wpf-remove-element-now");

        // By this code you replace the link outeHTML (the link itself) with
        // the link innerHTML (anything inside the link)
        link.outerHTML    =    link.innerHTML;
    }
);
```

Here you can find the running solution : ***[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tad6L/3/)***

**Note:** The inspiration for this solution found in the *[web page](http://coursesweb.net/javascript/innerhtml-outerhtml-get-replace-html-content_t)*.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a text node, so whatever you put in it will be interpreted as text. Instead, since you have the replacement tags predefined, you should create actual DOM elements to replace it with. Something like this could work: ***[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tad6L/1/)***

```
var em_elem = document.createElement('em');
em_elem.appendChild(document.createTextNode("replace"));

var strong_elem = document.createElement('strong');
strong_elem.appendChild(document.createTextNode("me"));

var container_span = document.createElement('span');
container_span.appendChild(em_elem);
container_span.appendChild(strong_elem);

// Make the replacement
link.parentNode.replaceChild(container_span, link);
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for your response, but, how to automate the above code ? I mean, an anchor link it can contains many other child elements, so, how can I perform the example code for unknown amount of child elements?

Comment: Well, you could use a regex to see what tags you've got in there. Something like `/<.*?>/gi` might work for that purpose. You could use the reverse of that to find the element contents: `/>.*?</gi` and save two arrays with all of this. Then clear the arrays up so you can feed them into a `for` loop to create each element in turn and finally attach them to some container `span` like I did here. I was actually working on this for code golf, I'll post some more in a minute, once I'm done with some housekeeping.

Comment: Here's the [golf question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/32964/reduce-html-to-n-characters-while-keeping-the-formatting) - I know this is probably not the elegant solution you're looking for, but it's the best I know. I'll post some sample code in a few minutes.

Comment: Here's a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/kGuhnRxq) of my golfing test so far. it's quite shitty but I don't have time to clean it up at the moment. The concept is the same though - even with that code, if you clean up the arrays a bit (get rid of ">" and "<") and arrange the elements in the proper sequence, you should have a workable setup that can be automated.